# How to get Flink taskmanager number before job submitted?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink Datastream job started by

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setParallelism(taskmanagernumber * x) // set env parallelism this line

env.addSource...map...addSink...
env.execute()
```

I want to control the env parallelism related to taskmanager number, like the code above.

Is there a way to do it? Or any workaround to set parallelism related to taskmanager number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [reactive scheduler](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/), which will automatically adapt the parallelism to whatever the cluster provides.

You don't have to set the parallelism in the job itself. You can set it on the command line when you launch the job:

```
flink run -p <parallelism> <jar-file> <arguments>
```

If you don't know how many slots the cluster has available, you could fetch the info from the REST API. `/overview` returns something like this:

```json
{
  taskmanagers: 2,
  slots-total: 2,
  slots-available: 2,
  jobs-running: 0,
  jobs-finished: 0,
  jobs-cancelled: 0,
  jobs-failed: 0,
  flink-version: "1.13.1",
  flink-commit: "a7f3192"
}
```

`slots-available` is what you're looking for. So you can do something like

```
flink run -p `curl -s http://localhost:8081/overview | jq '.["slots-available"]'` ...
```

Comment: What if I want to set it in code? like I have code loading config and set the config to Flink, I think command line is not a good way to handle this scenario.

Comment: In general I think it's better to keep operational config out of the code. But you can pass the value in as a parameter to the job, or call the REST API from inside your job. You could also set the parallelism in flink-conf.yaml.